# devexpress aspxdataview column issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm new to asp.net devexpress tools. I want to identify column value of `ASPxGridView` component.

How can i do this.Please help me to solve this problem

(can we do as below/or similar way)

```
ASPxGridView.column[1]
```

Comment: ASPxDataView contains collection of items, not columns. Also, you tagged your question with aspxgridview. That was mistake or you need to get aspxgridview column value?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..ya.i need to get aspxgridview column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get those values with:

[ASPxGridView.GetRowValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic)
[ASPxGridView.GetRowValuesByKeyValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuesByKeyValuetopic)

[List of all ASPxGridView members.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewMembersTopicAll)